# Merging rows with tabularx

Tags: tables

This seems to be quite a common question with ordinary tabular environments, but I have not been able to find an answer for this problem, or any like it, using the tabularx environment.

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Symbol (Name)}                              & \textbf{Example of Use}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{symbol\newline (Full name))}        & $x=\hdots$\\
\hline
                                                    & Description
\end{tabularx}
```

which produces:

[tableoutput http://mti20.user.srcf.net/latex_table.png](http://mti20.user.srcf.net/latex_table.png)

I am trying to make (Full name)) appear on the line below symbol without the horizontal line extending all the way to the left. I only want to third horizontal line to separate the column on the right.

How do I achieve this with the tabularx environment?

With many thanks,

Froskoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hrule` tells LaTeX to produce an horizontal line

Use `\cline{2-2}` instead (`\cline{start column - end column}`)

**Edit:** In a `\multirow` you can use `\parbox` to get the output you ask

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Symbol (Name)}                              & \textbf{Example of Use}\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2.9cm}{symbol\newline (Full name)}} & $x=\hdots$\
\cline{2-2}
                                                    & Description
\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Another possibility is just *not* to use `\multirow`

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Symbol (Name)}                              & \textbf{Example of Use}\\
\hline
symbol       & $x=\hdots$\\
\cline{2-2}
(Full name)  & Description
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: I think that you probably do not need to use `\multirow` here, just `\cline`...